# Convert client-side javascript using document.cookie into node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, commonjs

How can I use `document.cookie` in node? Please read further before replying.

My attempt at the node module:

```
var myModule = module.exports = function myModule(options) {
}

moduleName.getCookie = function(cname) {
    'use strict';
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
};

moduleName.setCookie = function(cname, cvalue, exdays) {

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
};
```

**In `index.js`:**

I tried using the `jsdom` module in my index.js

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var window = jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow;
var Cookies = require('cookies-js')(window);
```

**In `mymodule.js`:**

```
myModule.prototype.getCookie = function(cname) {
    Cookies.get(cname);
};

myModule.prototype.setCookie = function(cname, cvalue) {
    Cookies.set(cname, cvalue);
};
```

But I'm not sure how I would pass the `Cookies` referenced in `index.js` to `myModule` in foo.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I fully understood the question but why can't you put

```
var Cookies = require('cookies-js')(window);
myModule.prototype.getCookie = function(cname) {
    Cookies.get(cname);
};

myModule.prototype.setCookie = function(cname, cvalue) {
    Cookies.set(cname, cvalue);
};
```

into foo.js?

Comment: I'm trying to write a node module. Is it perfectly normal to add your requires in the module itself? Can you show me an example?

Comment: I updated the example. Yes, it is perfectly normal. Actually that is one of the benefits that dependencies are managed by the respective modules themselves and the consumer does not need to worry about them.